# How to get Amazon shop suggestions programmatically

Tags: amazon-product-api

If I fill out the search field on any Amazon shop site ([http://www.amazon.co.uk](http://www.amazon.co.uk/), for example), then I get a few suggestions like on the following screenshot:
[Amazon shop search suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6G2R.png)
I want to get these suggestions programmatically (any programming language is acceptable).

I have searched in AWS and Product Advertising API documentation, but have not found what I'm looking for.

On the other hand, I have found this service: www.keyword.io. It seems to be that they use Amazon API to provide their own service. I want to do the same directly, without any intermediate services.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: you're asking for help with a potential business venture?

Comment: @user3738936 No.